# What happened to Craster's son in S8E4?

Tags: game-of-thrones

At the end of *Game of Thrones* S8E4, before

> Arya kills the Night King,

we see all of the of the White Walkers gathered.

Where was the baby White Walker that the Night King created earlier in the show?

Do they grow up super fast? Was he left behind? If so then with whom and where?

Furthermore, we know that the baby Crastor sends isn't the first, does that mean some (or all???) of the other White Walkers are his sons as well?

Comment: Similar to question in sci-fi: [How does a baby who is turned into white walker grow into an adult White Walker?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133486/116116)

Comment: I'm hoping this question might be answered on the upcoming prequel series (The Long Night/Blood Moon/The Longest Night). It takes place thousands of years before GOT, but the synopsis includes the "true origins of the White Walkers", so it should be leading into the season 6 flashback scene of TNK being turned and could extend on all WW mythology.